# Convertion from Speed to (Speed)^-1

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

Using the [javax.measure](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/package-summary.html) library, I try to convert km/h in min/km.

However min/km is not a part of the units proposed by the [unit-ri](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri/blob/master/src/main/java/tec/units/ri/unit/Units.java).

So i tried to create my own unit: MINUTE_BY_KILOMETERS

```
import javax.measure.Quantity;
import javax.measure.Unit;
import javax.measure.quantity.Length;
import javax.measure.quantity.Speed;

import tec.units.ri.quantity.Quantities;
import tec.units.ri.unit.MetricPrefix;
import tec.units.ri.unit.Units;
```

```
    Quantity<Speed> speed = Quantities.getQuantity(10, Units.KILOMETRE_PER_HOUR);
    assertEquals("10 km/h", speed.toString());

    // Conversion m/s
    assertEquals("2.7777800000000004 m/s", speed.to(Units.METRE_PER_SECOND).toString());

    // Conversion min/km
    Unit<Speed> MINUTE_BY_KILOMETERS = Units.MINUTE.divide(MetricPrefix.KILO(Units.METRE)).asType(Speed.class);
    assertEquals("6 min/km", speed.to(MINUTE_BY_KILOMETERS).toString());
```

But I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: The unit: min/km is not compatible with quantities of type interface javax.measure.quantity.Speed
    at tec.units.ri.AbstractUnit.asType(AbstractUnit.java:274)
```

I suppose I have to create my own Type but I didn't find out how.

Can somebody provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out there was an .inverse function in order to do the conversion when needed.

So you have to keep the (distance / time) metrics in the code to do all the operations and conversions, and add a .inverse() at the end when you want your value:

```
Unit<Speed> KILOMETERS_BY_MINUTES = MetricPrefix.KILO(Units.METRE).divide(Units.MINUTE).asType(Speed.class);
assertEquals("5.9999952000038395 min/km", speed.to(KILOMETERS_BY_MINUTES).inverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Speed is defined as distance divided by time, so you cannot create a `Speed` unit of "minutes per kilometer". You could, however, create your own measurement of inverse speed, which is nothing more than a marker interface:

```
public interface InverseSpeed extends Quantity<InverseSpeed> {}
```

And then create such a unit:

```
Unit<InverseSpeed> MINUTE_BY_KILOMETERS = 
    Units.MINUTE.divide(MetricPrefix.KILO(Units.METRE)).asType(InverseSpeed.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, I suppose it respond to the answers.
However, if I do that, the new unit will be totally uncorrelated with minutes and kilometers unit, meaning i will have to manage all conversions in this unit by myself instead to be able to use the existing conversion (minutes -> hours, kilometers -> meters and so on).

That means loosing all the interest of using the library instead of developing my own converters.
But as I'm testing the library, I'm not sure it can do or not what I'm saying. Do you have any informations about that if you know this lib?